# Why do some code in java require try catch statements?

Tags: java, file-io

For example:

```
FileWriter saveFile = new FileWriter("text.txt");
```

This code shows the error:

```
Unhandled exception type IOException
```

What does this mean?

Comment: It doesn't really require it if you don't mind the program crashing after some invalid statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java has [checked exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions) mechanism.

It means every exception (which is not `RuntimeException`) that is thrown by a method must be handled by the method internally or be declared the is throwing it (in its declaration).

In your example,  the constructor of `FileWriter` is throwing `IOException`, so you should either handle it internally in the method by try-catch blocks, or make your method's signature declared it might throw it.

Answer (score 0):

There are exceptions which Java compiler forces to be handled by developer & need properly propagated to caller.
These exceptions fall under the category of checked exception(compile time exceptions). 
Either with `try{...}catch{...}` or with `throws` keyword these type of exceptions must be handled by developer.

The class `Exception` and any subclasses that are not also subclasses of `RuntimeException` are checked exceptions. Visit java doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)